# Finding minimum weight codewords in a Code over F9.

Tags: finite-fields, coding-theory

Hello everyone reading this. I seem to have a problem understanding weights in Coding Theory, and will attempt to provide a solution to a problem - please correct me where I am wrong.

---

Consider the finite field $F_9$, and x a solution  to the equation $X^2+1=0$. Let C be the code with parity-check matrix

$h=\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 1 & x  & 1\\
    0 & 1 & 1 &  1 & x 
\end{bmatrix}$

Find two code words of minimum weight.

---

My attempt at a solution: 
First, the code words shouldn't be zero. Any codeword $c=(c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4,c_5)$ will satisfy $ch=0$, that is 
$$
c_1+c_3+xc_4+c_5=0,c_2+c_3+c_4+xc_5=0 
$$
Solving for $c_1,c_2$ gives the basis 
$$
a=(-1,-1,1,0,0),b=(-x,-1,0,1,0),c=(-1,-x,0,0,1)
$$
So the dimension is 3, is this right?
Now, the weights. The weight is the number of nonzero elements, so I see that $w(a)=w(b)=w(c)=3$. So are $a,b$ just the required code words? And how does $x$ come into play?

Thanks in advance for any replies...

Comment: Your basis is correct. You still need to somehow prove that there are no words of weight two. Because there are 729 words altogether, listing them all, while doable, is not the recommended way. Are you familiar with a result relating the existence of a word of weight two to the set of columns of the check matrix?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes I read about that somewhere but I thought I could figure it out by hand. Guess there is no easy alternative... Oh well.

Comment: Also, do formulate this as a proper answer, I will accept it :)

Comment: I think that way **is** easy! All you need to do is to check that no small set of columns of $H$ is linearly independent over $\Bbb{F}_9$. In other words, calculate ten 2x2 determinants. Much simpler than generating a list of 729 vectors don¨t you think :-). I think I have done a similar calculation in the past so I will pass the offer. I don't want to give the impression that "getting paid twice for the same work" is ok. Go ahead and post the answer yourself!

Comment: Νο Ι won't. The prize belongs to you, whether you take it or not. Thanks!